# echarts/pyecharts: dataZoom starts at 0

Tags: python, echarts

I did the plot with pyecharts, but I end up modifying the html file generated directly, thus I added two tags in this question

**The problem**: I was trying to plot a line graph with pyecharts with data that looks like this:

```
x_data = [1596704736000,1596705336000,1596705937000,1596706538000,...]
y_data = [12,0,4,5,...]
```

where x_data is the timestamp. I did the plotting with pyecharts and the dataZoom options are:

```
datazoom_opts=[opts.DataZoomOpts(start_value=s_tamp - 60*60*1000, 
                                 end_value=e_tamp + 60*60*1000, 
                                 range_start=0, range_end=100),],
```

Here is the image:

[image]

as was shown on the image, the dataZoom starts with 1970, and the actual data starts with 1596704736000 (which is 2020/8/6).

My efforts:

1. I found that start will automatically make echarts ignore startValue, thus I tried removing range_start and range_end

**Outcome**: only the dataZoom scrollbar became shorter, the range still starts with 1970.

2. I changed the xAxis datatype from "time" to "category", "value"

**Outcome**:

- when changed to "value", the dataZoom still starts with 0 value
- when changed to "category", the dataZoom started with 2020/8/6 (great!) but the end of the dataZoom showed no dates and no points were shown on the plot.

3. I changed timestamp input to datetime

**Outcome**: the dataZoom still starts with 1970

4. I added `rangeMode: value` in dataZoom

**Outcome**: the zoom bar became very small to the end and showed the plot with the range of my data, but the bar range still starts with 1970

The html code is too long, I will post the xaxis options and the datazoom options as well as the pyecharts options for these two

This is from the generated HTML file

```
...
    "xAxis": [
        {
            "type": "time",
            "show": true,
            "scale": false,
            "nameLocation": "end",
            "nameGap": 15,
            "interval": 21600000.0,
            "gridIndex": 0,
            "inverse": false,
            "offset": 0,
            "splitNumber": 5,
            "min": 1596700714000,
            "max": 1597139914000,
            "minInterval": 0,
            "splitLine": {
                "show": false,
                "lineStyle": {
                    "show": true,
                    "width": 1,
                    "opacity": 1,
                    "curveness": 0,
                    "type": "solid"
                }
            },
...

    "dataZoom": [
        {
            "show": true,
            "type": "slider",
            "realtime": true,
            "startValue": 1596703383000,
            "endValue": 159714258300,
            "start": 0,
            "end": 100,
            "orient": "horizontal",
            "zoomLock": false,
            "filterMode": "filter"
        }
    ]
```

and this is the pyecharts setting for xaxis. The dataZoom pyecharts setting is mentioned before.

```
    xaxis_opts=opts.AxisOpts(
            type_ = 'time',
            min_ = s_tamp - 60*60*1000,    # the start time timestampe - 1 hour
            max_ = e_tamp + 60*60*1000,    # the end time timestampe + 1 hour
            interval = 5*24*60*60*1000/(5*4)    # 5 days interval
        )
```

Anyone who have any clue to this? If the information is not enough to solve the problem please comment to let me know, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem and adding `is_scale=True` in xAxis options worked for me.

```
xaxis_opts = opts.AxisOpts(
    type_='time',
    is_scale=True,
)
```

Complete example:

```
from pyecharts.charts import Line
from pyecharts import options as opts

line = Line()

xaxis_opts = opts.AxisOpts(
    type_='time',
    is_scale=True,
)

yaxis_opts = opts.AxisOpts(
    type_='value'
)

datazoom_opts = opts.DataZoomOpts(
    type_='slider',
    start_value=1596705336000,
    end_value=1596706538000,
)

line.add_xaxis(
    [1596704736000,
     1596705336000,
     1596705937000,
     1596706538000,
     1596707538000])
line.add_yaxis('values', [0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
line.set_global_opts(
    xaxis_opts=xaxis_opts,
    yaxis_opts=yaxis_opts,
    datazoom_opts=datazoom_opts
)

print(line.dump_options())
line.render()
```

Result:

[See on Imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ltky.png)